# Image hover scaling not working inside a table (blocked by thead/tfoot)

Tags: html, css

Relevant jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/theanine/0d8vbrnt/13/

```
img.owl {
    width: 100px;
}
img.owl:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(2);
  -moz-transform: scale(2);
  -o-transform: scale(2);
  transform: scale(2);
  transition: all 1s;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
}
table {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
table thead{
    display:block;
    height:48px;
    overflow:auto;
}
table tbody{
    display:block;
    height:calc(99.5vh - 87px);
    height:calc((var(--vh, 1vh) * 100) - 91px);
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Using z-index didn't seem to help.  However removing "overflow-y: scroll" did work.  The problem is I need to keep this because the goal is to have header/footer rows (and the page itself) that remain static as the tbody is scrolled, and images that scale when moused over (and don't get blocked by the header/footer rows).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is

```
img.owl {
    width: 100px;
}
img.owl:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(2);
  -moz-transform: scale(2);
  -o-transform: scale(2);
  transform: scale(2);
  transition: all 1s;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
}
table {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
table thead{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
    display:block;
    height:28px;
    overflow:auto;
}
table tbody{
    display:block;
    height:calc(99.5vh - 87px);
    height:calc((var(--vh, 1vh) * 100) - 91px);
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding: 35px 0;
}
tr{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
tbody::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
}
```

I just made a few changes in your code, and with the help of a little bit of flexbox I think I got it! let me know if that help you

Comment: thanks for your effort, but this doesn't work.  The images go under thead in your code sample, and tfoot isn't static.

Answer (score 0):

You can use position fixed

```
table thead {
    display:block;
    height:48px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white  
}

table tbody{
    display:block;
    height:calc(99.5vh - 87px);
    height:calc((var(--vh, 1vh) * 100) - 91px);
}
```

Comment: Please use code formatting for code blocks, it makes them easier to read. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: @Gustavo this doesn't work -- the thead element will clobber over the tbody, so the first row(s) will be partially/fully obscurred.